# simultaneous Rosbag record and playback

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, laser, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I playback .bag at the same time as it is getting recorded ? Can I map my laser scans in real-time ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195912/simultaneous-rosbag-record-and-playback/) by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; you cannot play back a log file while it is being recorded - and it doesn't make sense to try.

If you want to run mapping online, just run mapping on your robot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-25**:
You can record on a running system, it does not prevent other downstream processes from receiving.